# Cannot access 4 day weather - MSN weather

Tags: ios, xml, weather, weather-api

I have been using this msn weather api for couple of years now

[Programatically access weather info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180388/programatically-access-weather-info)

As of today I get the following error in my app. Access Denied. It could be a glitch or a permanent shutdown by microsoft. I don't know but is there any other free 4 day weather forecast api that I can use to get weather in a XML format? Saddest part is that I have been using this api in at least 20 of my apps and now I am scrambling to find a solution.

I did send an email to weather@microsoft.com couple of hours ago but as predicted no response.

```
    2014-12-10 07:46:40.321 Big Clock[10890:230027] locationStr: http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?weadegreetype=F&culture=en-US&weasearchstr=Detroit,MI

    2014-12-10 07:46:40.461 Big Clock[10890:230027] XML: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><weatherdata xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><weather errormessage="Access denied: Please contact weather@microsoft.com if you need access to this API." /></weatherdata>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not alone in this.
For the time being, passing an additional query string "&src=outlook" worked for me.

Sample Working URL:

http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?weasearchstr=45236&culture=en-US&weadegreetype=F&src=outlook

Try it out and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: thanks buddy. that did the trick. I am going to wait a couple more days to see if microsoft completely shuts this down or not. Otherwise I will have to start looking for some other api

Answer (score 1):

This is Ram from Microsoft. The existing service will be deprecated soon. 
Please resend your email to the alias one more time so we can take it offline. We had an email hiccup so the alias should work now.

Please do not use the outlook as src value.

Comment: would you able to tell us when will this service be deprecated, i.e. shutdown completely. I would rather not find this as a surprise when I wake up and would like to know this a few months ahead of time so that I can plan ahead for all my apps that use msn weather.

Comment: Hi Sam
We are working out the details. At this time I don't have an exact date for you, but we plan to do this by sometime in March end. That said we will reconvene on this next year to figure out how this will be deprecated. Please stay tuned and I will ensure to provide an update here as well as publish officially.

Answer (score 0):

We are writing to notify you that the Microsoft Weather API will no longer be available for download and will be discontinued as of April 15, 2015, meaning it will no longer provide weather data.  Accordingly, please remove the Microsoft Weather API from any of your products or apps that currently use it.

Here is a list of external providers who might be able to support your needs if you are interested in obtaining an alternate weather API:

```
http://api.accuweather.com/ 
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html?MR=1
https://developer.forecast.io/
```

Disclaimer:  Microsoft and Microsoft Weather are not affiliated or associated with any of the above companies in any way.

Thank You 
Microsoft Weather Team

Comment: Thanks Ram for the heads up I can now plan for my app updates. I really hate to see MSN weather go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ram we now know that MSN weather api will be gone by April 15th, 2015.

If anyone wants a free weather alternate then try this

http://openweathermap.org/price_detailes

```
Calls per minute (no more than) 3,000
Calls per day (no more than)    4,000,000
```

This is the most I have seen any weather provide give out for free. I hope it helps.